# Ways to make square from a grid uneven-spaced

Tags: combinatorics

Given 9 vertical lines spaced 1 cm and 6 horizontal lines spaced 2 cm , find how many squares are there?

[image: grid]

EDIT:
I've thought about a general case and found that the ways to make **S** sized square in $MxN(M\ge N)$ rectangle is (M-S+1)(N-S+1). Summing this all the way to N is
$$\sum_{S=1}^N (M-S+1)(N-S+1) =\frac{N(N+1)(3M-N-1)}{6} $$
and I'm stuck after this.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: But you can't make an $S=1$ square in your grid.  Your sum would be correct if the cells were $1 \times 1$ and the grid were $M \times N$ cells (not grid lines).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  go through the sizes of squares.  The smallest is $2 \times 2$ cm.  How many ways to choose the top line of a $2 \times 2$ square?  How many ways to choose the left side?  Now do $4 \times 4$ and on.

Answer (score 0):

It takes 2 horizontal and 1 vertical rectangle to make a ‘smallest’ square. Each of these can be framed in 7 places horizontally and 5 places vertically. The next size square is double that and can occupy 5 X 4 places. The next  size is 3 vertical and 6 horizontal boxes the can be found ing 3X3 places. The next and largest square uses 8 horizontal and 4 vertical rectangles and can ‘move’ between only 2 vertical places in the grid. The total is 7*5+5*4+3*3+2 = 35+20+3+5=60.